# ImportError: No module named db when using chatterbot

Tags: python, python-2.7, chatterbot

I am trying to buid a chatbot. so i installed chatterbot package.
the python code is following:

```
from chatterbot import TalkWithCleverbot
talk = TalkWithCleverbot()
talk.begin()
```

but i am getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\JERIN\Desktop\bottobot.py", line 2, in <module>
   talk = TalkWithCleverbot()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 157, in     __init__
 super(TalkWithCleverbot, self).__init__()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in  __init__
 from jsondb.db import Database
 ImportError: No module named db
```

I tried installing jsondb and db packages, but there is no good. Please help me

Comment: `TalkWithCleverbot` removed from chatterbot codebase. If you are here it's good to know that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is highlighting the issue -- there's no `db` object to import from `jsondb` for the call in `__init__.py`.

```
def __init__(self, name="bot", logging=True):
      from jsondb.db import Database
                  ^^ this doesn't exist
```

I found the source for the ['ChatterBot' module on GitHub](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) and it appears that the 'jsondb' that the author is importing is not the one you'd get if you installed from [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsondb).  Instead, the author is expecting you to use *his* [jsondb module that can be found on GitHub.](https://github.com/gunthercox/jsondb)

You can likely resolve this by uninstalling the jsondb that you retreived from pip:

```
pip uninstall jsondb
```

and installing the ChatterBot author's jsondb module:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/gunthercox/jsondb.git
```

You ran into this error because the ChatterBot author is assuming that you had *his package* named jsondb installed and did not include the dependency in a typical manner.

Comment: @JerinAMathews You're welcome.  I would have run into the same error if I was installing ChatterBot.

Comment: Thank you from me, also!